# Pass Django variables to javascripts

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, area-chart

I am stuck into a problem, I want to pass django variable to javascripts but I can't.

**views.py**

```
def dashboard_view(request):
    months_before = 5
    now = datetime.utcnow()
    from_datetime = now - relativedelta(months=months_before)
    modified_from_datetime = from_datetime.replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    month = Btdetail.objects.filter(DatePur__gte=modified_from_datetime).count()
    return render(request, "dashboard.html", {'month': month})
```

I want to embed **month** value to javascripts **data**

my html **script function** is

```
<script>
    var xValues = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
    new Chart("myChart3", {
    type: "line",
    data: {
        labels: xValues,
        datasets: [{
            data: [5,10,20,15,20,5,15,40,10,12,24,35],
            borderColor: "red",
            fill: false
            }]
        },
        options: {
            legend: {display: false}
        }
    });
</script>
```

actually I want to create a Area bar, all things are good but javascript functions cant get value from django database and if there is another way to do this please tell me
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bJzE.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your `anypage.html` inside `<body>  </body>` tag

```
<body>
   <p> text for example </p>
   <div> some divs </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       var month_count = {{ month }};
   </script>
</body>
```

it will initiate `month_count` variable on your `anypage.html` and you could use it with javascripts inside this `anypage.html`

Comment: I also try this method but not work

Comment: do you get any error? try `console.log(month_count)`

Answer (score 0):

###### views.py

```
import json

        
def your_page(request):
    context = {
        "some_list": json.dumps([1,2,3]),
    }
    return render(request, "your_template.html", context)
```

###### javascript

```
<script>
    const some_list = JSON.parse(`{{some_list|safe}}`);
</script>
```

Comment: whats the point of serializeing passing variables?

Comment: He doesn't want to pass just a simple variable. He wants to pass a list.

Comment: I will create list manually later but now I want one variable that I used in one of data values and my value store in **month** variable

Comment: when I write JSON.parse in script function the charts disappear otherwise it' s show properly