# Is it possible to deliver django toast messages via frontend

Tags: javascript, django, django-messages

Tryna achieve sending notifications through Javascript logic instead of Django views, I want to replace alert() in this Javascript function with Django contrib messages(toasts). Something that would look like this in views `messages.success(request, f"test successful")` Is it possible to achieve the same thing with javascript?

js

```
function TestBtn(id) {
    alert("test successful");
}
```

html

```
<a onclick="TestBtn('btn');return false;"></a>
```

Comment: you need to pass variable to html via contex, and then put this variable in alert, here is how you can do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72215399/pass-django-variables-to-javascripts/72215521#72215521

Comment: @oruchkin It doesn't look very clean, every time I would try to add an alert message, I would need to set up contexts, also it would display in alert format which I don't want